# Como puedo bloquear la orientacion a horizontal en xamarion IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Como puedo bloquear la orientación a horizontal en xamarin IOS. Solo que se pueda ver en vertical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ver en la documentación como realizarlo para iOS con Xamarin, tienes que definir la propiedad de orientación a tu Actividad,

ya sea Landscape (horizontal):

```
ScreenOrientation.Landscape
```

o Portrait (vertical):

```
ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

Ejemplo:

```
 [Activity (Label = "MyRotatingApp.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)] //Esto es lo que controla la orientacion.
```

Esta es la documentación:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation/#Controlling_Orientation